# Stopping error messages from appearing in terminal

Tags: terminal, vlc, suppress-warnings

I am executing a command in terminal which is

```
cvlc song.amr
```

Problem is though the song is being played, I am getting some message after I am executing the instruction. The message is

```
VLC media player 1.1.9 The Luggage (revision exported)
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_ADDRESS")
Blocked: call to unsetenv("DBUS_ACTIVATION_BUS_TYPE")
[0x85de7cc] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
```

Can anyone tell me how to stop this message from coming.
Like in gcc, when we don't want warning message to come, we instruct it by giving an option as

```
cc -w program.c
```

Is there anyway, by which I can stop that message from coming. Or is it that solving that problem is the only way to stop it from coming. How to solve it then. Or else can I save those messages in some other file and stop it from coming in terminal, like how we do with this '>' redirection operator in terminal for storing the output somewhere else.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried the redirection as u suggested?

Comment: @KarthikT, Yes I tried simple redirection, but it is not working. Or else do I have to modify the redirection more with the help of pipe symbol? If you know can you please suggest me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

does this work? `cvlc song.amr &> /dev/null`? otherwise command line options like what you suggest are program specific and i dunno abt cvlc's options, maybe u can try `cvlc -h` and see if it has a silent mode

Comment: Thanks a lot. :) The instruction what you gave is working. Can you also explain me kindly what it is doing actually?

Comment: > redirects stdout (regular output) but not stderr(error output) &> does both, more details [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html)